# Handling higher clamping voltage of IsoMOV - MOV/GDT Hybrid

Tags: ac, mains, tvs, surge-protection, mov

I'm working on an ac mains control circuit and came across [IsoMOV a new hybrid MOV/GDT](https://www.bourns.com/products/circuit-protection/isomov) for surge suppression. This appears to be a straightforward replacement for a standard TPMOV with additional benefits of extended life and predictable failure mode as a short. The way I understand, the only con seems to be the higher clamping voltage and peak voltage. In my case, I would like to protect the circuit from short high-voltage spikes, but also sustained higher than rated voltages, e.g. connecting 230VAC to the device which will only be rated for 120VAC. I realize that MOV's are the standard, however would it be acceptable to use this ISOMOV followed by a PTC fuse and TVS as shown here? I assume the TVS will handle most of the cases here, and the MOV would only come into play when a huge surge has to be handled. Otherwise, what are other simple ways of improving response times and handling sustained over-voltages?

[image]

Comment: There might be a case for using a TVS and GDT and, avoiding the flaky failure mode of an MOV and F1.

Comment: My understanding of this new hybrid is the failure mode is always a short, so that it will protect the downstream device via blowing the fuse, and this also avoids having to monitor the status of a thermally-protected MOV. The GDT is actually built inline to the MOV for IsoMov. I'm just not sure if it is safe to use a TVS following this to handle the cases where the IsoMOV doesn't come into play.

Comment: Is T1 actually a transformer, or just representing a downstream load?

Comment: There will be a transformer, but this is a simplification. There are probably two transformers and also some optoisolators on the line side. This will also feed a complementary MOSFET SSR, and current sensor as well.

Comment: You are allowed to put a x rated .22 uf capacitor by the load, which helps with very short surges. TPMOVs are bulky and expensive, but will live long enough to make sure your fast-blow fuse blows first.